# Improve vimrc with external configuration is possible?

Tags: vim, phpunit

This script:

```vim
function! RunPhpUnit()
    let l:filename = expand('%')
    if l:filename !~# 'Test\.php$'
        let l:filename=substitute(l:filename, '\.php$', 'Test.php', '')
    endif
    let l:filename=substitute(l:filename, 'code\/classes', 'spec\/unit', '')
    return ':!vendor/bin/phpunit ' . l:filename . "\<CR>"
endfunction
:noremap <expr> <leader>t RunPhpUnit()
```

assumes that phpunit is placed in `vendor/bin/phpunit` and production code is located in `code/classes` folder and test are in `spec/unit`. But, ... how can I improve my VimL function to configure `phpunit` position, test and production files???

Answer (score 1):

The main question is: Why would you configure those? If this is to adapt to different environments (when you use Vim on more than one system), that's best done via global variables, like most plugins do (and this will enable you to publish your script as a plugin on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/), to share with others). For example, change

```
return ':!vendor/bin/phpunit ' . l:filename . "\<CR>"
```

to

```
return ':!' . g:RunPhpUnit_Filespec . ' ' . l:filename . "\<CR>"
```

and define a default for that variable:

```
if ! exists('g:RunPhpUnit_Filespec')
    let g:RunPhpUnit_Filespec = 'vendor/bin/phpunit'
endif
```

---

If you have different projects on the *same* system, and may use variants of your mapping concurrently, you could use *buffer-local* configuration variables (starting with `b:`), or pass in the variables into your `RunPhpUnit( PhpUnitFilespec )` function, and then define several mapping variants.

Comment: Wouldn't it being better to store those settings in a text file under the project root? the function could access those settings.

Comment: @hek2mgl: Why do custom parsing (even if it's simple) when you can just use Vimscript? There are several _local vimrc_ plugins (or built-in `exrc`) that allow configuration for a directory subtree; this can then be easily combined with my suggested buffer-local config vars.

Comment: If there are already such facilities - even better! :) Didn't know.. Probably you could mention it in your answer..